# Disk mount failed with result 'dependency'

Tags: linux, debian, mount, fstab, automounting

I mount drive using command `mount` and modify `fstab` file (so disk should be visible after restart). Unfortunately, after system reboot, mount isn't visible in the system

`lsblk -a` says, disk is configured but without mounting point.

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  250G  0 disk 
vda    254:0    0  100G  0 disk 
├─vda1 254:1    0  100G  0 part /
└─vda2 254:2    0    2M  0 part
```

Here is a log from `journalctl`:

```
May 15 09:23:34 srv  systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-XXX\XXX\XXXX\ZZZZZ\YYYY.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-XXX\XXX\XXXX\ZZZZZ\YYYY.device/start timed >
May 15 09:23:34 srv  systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX.
May 15 09:23:34 srv  systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Mount DO Volume dev-volume.
May 15 09:23:34 srv  systemd[1]: mnt-dev_volume.mount: Job mnt-dev_volume.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

How to fix it and mount disk automatically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was due to configuration conflict, it occurs after disk migration in Digital ocean, which resulted in a change of the disk UUID. Check those two configurations: `/etc/fstab/` (disk config) and  `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-volume_*.mount` (mounting config) file.

In this case, the incorrect UUID was pointed out, causing systemd to attempt mounting it despite the configuration set in `fstab`.

**Solution:**

1. Remove /etc/systemd/system/mnt-volume_*.mount file
2. Remount disk (`mount` command + adjust `fstab`)
3. Restart system → it should work.